# Zabbix Logfile monitoring doesn't work

Tags: nginx, log-files, zabbix, zabbix-agent

I am trying to set up Zabbix monitoring for a nginx webserver.
The file is located in `/var/log/nginx/accesss.log`.
I also already modified the access rights and checked that the zabbix agent on the web server can read the logfile.

I configured the log monitor as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vrQf.png).
I get the following "error" as can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pz0cc.png).